# How to copy data from one sheet1 to another same type of sheet2 having same column if sheet 2 has sheet matching column

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets sheet3 and sheet4. Sheet3 is blank sheet as below:

[image]

sheet 4 as below

[image]

Now I need to copy all the data from sheet 4 to sheet 3 where sheet 3 has matching Names e.g ABC, DEF etc and for rest put 0 in sheet 3.

Comment: What did you try? Also do not punt links in your question. Please refer the [ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: You don't need VBA for this. This can be achieved by `VLookUp`. You can use this as a formula in your cells in `Sheet3`

Comment: In sheet3 B2 put `=SUMIF(Sheet4!$A:$A,$A2,Sheet4!B:B)` and copy right down... that is all you need to do

Comment: Hi ADK. In general we ask that beginners show what they have tried, or at least what research they have done. We are very keen that Stack Overflow does not get known as a place where free work is done, so if you can make your own independent effort for your next question, **and also show that in the question**, readers will very much appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: My simplest way is to put the values from sheet 4 into an array.  Then scan the first column in sheet 3 to see if each row in sheet 3 has a match in the array.  If so then copy the values, if not then enter 0.

Answer (score 0):

In your sheet 3, enter the below formula and drag it right and then down,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet4!$A:$E,MATCH($A2,Sheet4!$A:$A,0),COLUMN()),0)
```

[image]

Note:- Sheet 4 data should be in columns A to E like below.

[image]

Comment: @ADK please mark the answer as correct to make the question resolved

Answer (score 0):

First try to do it on the same sheet to get the idea. Like this:

[image]

Then transfer it to the new sheet.
The formula you set in *B6* is 
`=INDEX($B$2:$D$4,MATCH($A6,$A$2:$A$4,0),MATCH(B$5,$B$1:$D$1,0))`

Then you can stretch it to the right and down.

The idea is that you give the location of the value in `B2:D4`, by selecting the correct column and the correct row with the `Index()` formula.

The correct column is the column, which matches `B5`, `C5` or `D5` in range `B1:D1`.

The correct row is the row that matches the value in `A6`, `A7` or `A8` in `A2:A4`.

Thus, the formula in `B6` will return row 3 and column 2. In range `B2:D4` row 3  and column 2 has a value 8.